# React Chrome Extension - `chrome.tabs.executeScript` not consistent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, react-hooks

I want click a button to inject a script to grab some DOM items using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. For some reason, it only works once on an initial page load, but if I click the button again, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` returns `[null]`. Here is my code, the function of interest is `handleClick`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
// import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import * as chromeAsync from 'chrome-extension-async';

function getFnBody(fn) {
  const fnStr = fn.toString();
  return fnStr.substring(fnStr.indexOf('{') + 1, fnStr.lastIndexOf('}'));
}

async function clearLinks({ key = 'default' } = {}) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  await chrome.storage.local.set({ [key]: {} });
}

async function getLinks({ key = 'default' } = {}) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  return (await chrome.storage.local.get([key]))[key];
}

async function appendLinks({ key = 'default', links } = {}) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const data = await chrome.storage.local.get([key]);
  const allLinks = data[key] || {};

  links.map((l) => {
    const date = allLinks[l];
    if (!date) {
      allLinks[l] = Date.now();
    }
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  await chrome.storage.local.set({ [key]: allLinks });
}

async function handleClick() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  const activeTab = tabs[0];

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const results = await chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTab.id, {
    code: getFnBody(getLinkedInHrefs),
  });

  const hrefs = JSON.parse(results);
  await appendLinks({ links: hrefs });

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  await chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTab.id, {
    code: getFnBody(clickNext),
  });
}

// Chrome Injected

function getLinkedInHrefs() {
  // window.location.toString();
  const hrefList = [];
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.search-result__info a.search-result__result-link',
  );
  list.forEach((node) => {
    hrefList.push(node.href);
  });
  JSON.stringify(hrefList);
}

function clickNext() {
  document.querySelector('.artdeco-pagination__button--next').click();
}

function Home() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      const links = await getLinks();
    }
    init();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className="home-page">
        <Button onClick={handleClick}>
          Let's Fucking GO
        </Button>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but I had another, older (React 15) version that was working, but after scaffolding out a new app using `create-react-app`, it only works on the first reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFnBody` in your code extracts the contents of the functions so `const` declarations pollute the global scope of the content script's context (the "isolated world") which prevents the code from running again because `const` or `let` variables can be declared just once in a scope.

The easiest solution is to remove `getFnBody` and simply wrap the code in an IIFE:

```
const results = await chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTab.id, {
  code: `(${getLinkedInHrefs})()`,
});
```

And of course you'll need to use `return` in these injected functions:

```
function getLinkedInHrefs() {
  //.........................
  return hrefList;
}
```

Note there's no need to do JSON.stringify/JSON.parse as this is performed internally anyway.